# Mongoose nested update "Cannot use the part.." to traverse

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a question about updating nested documents in MongoDB. I was using Mongoose but because I couldn't manage to find the answer, so I switched to my Robo3T shell (v.1.1.1).

What I want to do is insert an answer to a question in a round. The document has an array of rounds. Each round has an array of questions. Each question has an array of answers. 
In a later stadium I also want to be able to update that answer, but I guess when I get this right, that won't be that difficult.

I have this answer that I want to insert:

```
{
    answer: "Intelligent answer",
    approved: false,
    teamId: ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e5f1"),
    id: ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e5f1")
  }
```

I have this document structure:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e5f1"),
"name" : "AvengersQuizz",
"password" : "verysecure",
"status" : "Playing",
"rounds" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "questions" : [ 
            {
                "status" : "Closed",
                "questionId" : ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2d7"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e623"),
                "answers" : [ 
                    {
                        "answer" : "a",
                        "approved" : false,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c8"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e625")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "answer" : "ab",
                        "approved" : true,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c9"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e624")
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "status" : "Closed",
                "questionId" : ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2d5"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e620"),
                "answers" : [ 
                    {
                        "answer" : "a",
                        "approved" : false,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c8"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e622")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "answer" : "ab",
                        "approved" : true,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c9"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e621")
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "status" : "Closed",
                "questionId" : ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2d4"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e61d"),
                "answers" : [ 
                    {
                        "answer" : "a",
                        "approved" : false,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c8"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e61f")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "answer" : "ab",
                        "approved" : true,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c9"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e61e")
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "status" : "Closed",
                "questionId" : ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2d3"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e61a"),
                "answers" : [ 
                    {
                        "answer" : "a",
                        "approved" : false,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c8"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e61c")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "answer" : "ab",
                        "approved" : true,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c9"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e61b")
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "status" : "Closed",
                "questionId" : ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2d6"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e617"),
                "answers" : [ 
                    {
                        "answer" : "a",
                        "approved" : false,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c8"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e619")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "answer" : "ab",
                        "approved" : true,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c9"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e618")
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "status" : "Closed",
                "questionId" : ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2db"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e614"),
                "answers" : [ 
                    {
                        "answer" : "a",
                        "approved" : false,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c8"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e616")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "answer" : "ab",
                        "approved" : true,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c9"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e615")
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "status" : "Closed",
                "questionId" : ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2da"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e611"),
                "answers" : [ 
                    {
                        "answer" : "a",
                        "approved" : false,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c8"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e613")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "answer" : "ab",
                        "approved" : true,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c9"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e612")
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "status" : "Closed",
                "questionId" : ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2d9"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e60e"),
                "answers" : [ 
                    {
                        "answer" : "a",
                        "approved" : false,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c8"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e610")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "answer" : "ab",
                        "approved" : true,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c9"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e60f")
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "status" : "Closed",
                "questionId" : ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2d8"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e60b"),
                "answers" : [ 
                    {
                        "answer" : "a",
                        "approved" : false,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c8"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e60d")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "answer" : "ab",
                        "approved" : true,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c9"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e60c")
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "status" : "Closed",
                "questionId" : ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2df"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e608"),
                "answers" : [ 
                    {
                        "answer" : "a",
                        "approved" : false,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c8"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e60a")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "answer" : "ab",
                        "approved" : true,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c9"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e609")
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "status" : "Closed",
                "questionId" : ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2de"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e605"),
                "answers" : [ 
                    {
                        "answer" : "a",
                        "approved" : false,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c8"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e607")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "answer" : "ab",
                        "approved" : true,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c9"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e606")
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "status" : "Closed",
                "questionId" : ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2dd"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e602"),
                "answers" : [ 
                    {
                        "answer" : "a",
                        "approved" : false,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c8"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e604")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "answer" : "ab",
                        "approved" : true,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c9"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e603")
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "categories" : [ 
            ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2cb"), 
            ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2cc"), 
            ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2cd")
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "questions" : [ 
            {
                "status" : "Closed",
                "questionId" : ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2d7"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e5ff"),
                "answers" : [ 
                    {
                        "answer" : "a",
                        "approved" : false,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c8"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e601")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "answer" : "ab",
                        "approved" : true,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c9"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e600")
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "status" : "Open",
                "questionId" : ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2d5"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e5fc"),
                "answers" : [ 
                    {
                        "answer" : "a",
                        "approved" : false,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c8"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e5fe")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "answer" : "ab",
                        "approved" : true,
                        "teamId" : ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c9"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e5fd")
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "status" : "Queued",
                "questionId" : ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2d4"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e5fb"),
                "answers" : []
            }, 
            {
                "status" : "Queued",
                "questionId" : ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2d3"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e5fa"),
                "answers" : []
            }, 
            {
                "status" : "Queued",
                "questionId" : ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2d6"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e5f9"),
                "answers" : []
            }, 
            {
                "status" : "Queued",
                "questionId" : ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2db"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e5f8"),
                "answers" : []
            }, 
            {
                "status" : "Queued",
                "questionId" : ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2da"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e5f7"),
                "answers" : []
            }, 
            {
                "status" : "Queued",
                "questionId" : ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2d9"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e5f6"),
                "answers" : []
            }, 
            {
                "status" : "Queued",
                "questionId" : ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2d8"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e5f5"),
                "answers" : []
            }, 
            {
                "status" : "Queued",
                "questionId" : ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2df"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e5f4"),
                "answers" : []
            }, 
            {
                "status" : "Queued",
                "questionId" : ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2de"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e5f3"),
                "answers" : []
            }, 
            {
                "status" : "Queued",
                "questionId" : ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2dd"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e5f2"),
                "answers" : []
            }
        ],
        "categories" : [ 
            ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2cb"), 
            ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2cc"), 
            ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2cd")
        ]
    }
],
"teams" : [ 
    ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c8"), 
    ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2c9"), 
    ObjectId("59faf27c40b719352a62e2ca")
],
"__v" : 0
```

}

This is what I have tried to use:

```
db.getCollection('quizzes').update({
   rounds: {
     $elemMatch: {
       _id: 2,
       questions: {
        $elemMatch: {
          questionId: ObjectId("59faf27d40b719352a62e2d5")}}
                    }
                  }
                 }, 
   {
    $push: {
      "rounds.$[rounds].questions.$[questions].answers": {
         answer: "Intelligent answer",
         approved: false,
         teamId: ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e5f1"),
         id: ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e5f1")
       }
    }
   }, {
   arrayFilters: [
   {"rounds._id": 2}, 
   {"questions._id": ObjectId("59faf27e40b719352a62e5fc")}]
   })
```

It returns the following error:

```
cannot use the part (rounds of rounds.$[rounds].questions.$[questions].answers) to traverse the element ({rounds: [ { _id: 1, questions: [ { status: "Closed", questionId: ObjectId('59faf27d40b719352a62e2d7'), _id:  ... (cut off because of space)
```

I see similar questions, but they do not answer my question fully. I have tried those answers but still cannot seem to make this work. Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The question is answered quite fully. `arrayFilters` of the positional filtered [`$[<identifier>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) updates are **NOT** yet available until **MongoDB 3.6**. Just as is stated on **Bold Text** on the referenced question. This version is **not yet released**. You deal with nested updates just as the rest of the body of the answers there describe until you actually have a version that supports this. Right now you do not.